# how to render layout from a database in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible to read a string from a text data field and render it as a layout?

If I use this, it looks for a file `1.html.erb` under layouts:

```
layout: '1'
```

Comment: This is an interesting question (+1), but do the layouts really vary that much per database record? Layouts are designed to provide a consistent framework for the presentation of information in HTML. So more typically, there may be a small set of layouts to handle classes of information. Could you give an example of how these vary?

Comment: They will vary a lot. I am trying to display sports results from a sports organisation with a layout that makes it look like the data is from their own website. There will be rules about js and css inclusions. The custom layout is for a single page only. A link to my site gives me the id and I publish their results with their own layout.

Comment: may be `render :inline` works for you? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render-with-inline

Comment: Following up with @j03w suggestion, what happens if you select the layout attribute from your active record into a variable, say, `custom_layout` and do `render layout: custom_layout`? You haven't provided much code, so I'm not sure how to describe it in any more detail than that.

Comment: The book "Crafting Rails Applications" - http://pragprog.com/book/jvrails/crafting-rails-applications has a chapter "Retrieving View Templates from Custom Stores" which implements a SqlTemplate ActionView::Resolver - doesn't talk about layout specifically and might be overkill for your situation, but worth checking out

Comment: There are also more secure alternatives one of them is [liquid](http://liquidmarkup.org/) this way. There is a couple of [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/125-dynamic-layouts) on the topic which might relevant to what you are doing.

Comment: This idea was just a work around the single origin problem anyway. I just installed rack_cors to allow cross site ajax insertion of my data.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the name of a layout in the call to render

```
def show
  @team = Team.find_by name: 'Red Sox'
  render action: :show, layout: @team.preferred_layout
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

All of the official rails docs are a great resource

To render text use

```
render text: "OK"
```